# MariaDB doesn't use index on 1 column self-join due to low selectivity (all NULLs)

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, mariadb

We have a query that looks for duplicates in one of our tables, based on an identifier that is rarely available, let's call it `rareIdentifier INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL`. We have a single-column regular old index on this column.

The query in question looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM
    widget a INNER JOIN widget b
ON a.rareIdentifier = b.rareIdentifier;
```

The problem is that for a recent duplicate-finding run, we actually had `0` rows with a value for `rareIdentifier`; i.e. all rows had `NULL` for this column. MariaDB decided not to use the index, opting for a `Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)` approach which scanned the whole table.

But `NULL`s cannot equal each other! So why is it trying to compare each pair of rows?

I understand that MySQL/MariaDB won't use an index if its selectivity is too low. I believe this is the case here. In fact, it seems like just having 1 value in the index means the query is pretty much instantaneous.

The table is an InnoDB table.

Comment: What are your current indexes on that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB may not be smart enough to realise that comparing to `NULL` is always `NULL`, therefore falsy. Perhaps it just decided that "all values are the same, so they *must* be equal" (but in fact I really don't know).

As a workaround, adding `... AND a.rareIdentifier IS NOT NULL` should give the optimiser enough of a hint.

Answer (score 0):

This may be faster in most cases, especially if there are many rows with the same `rareIdentifier`.

```
SELECT  rareIdentifier, MIN(id), MAX(id), COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE rareIdentifier IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY rareIdentifier
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Or you could use `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` instead of min & max.  (However, if there are a lot of dups, the list will be truncated.)

Assuming InnoDB and `INDEX(rareIdentifier)`, this `SELECT` should be a very efficient 'range' scan of the index.

Back to your question...

> actually had 0 rows ... MariaDB decided not to use the index

I used to see that a lot in older versions of MySQL.  I wonder if Oracle fixed, but MariaDB missed the fix.